# How do I evaluate the resistors that have the equivalent voltage drop?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

I've been given the following circuit:

[image]

I basically need to evaluate the resistors that have the equivalent voltage drop. Could I get your dear assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could calculate all this out the hard way assinging voltages to nodes and then writing a big system of simultanious equations.

But the much easier way to solve this particular problem is to exploit symetry.

We can replace the three resistors in the lower-right corner with one 4K resistor through series and paralell combinations.

Once we do that, we see that what remains of the triangle is symetrical. We can exploit this symetry to quickly find a number of pairs of resistors that have the same voltage across them.

---

[image]

In the image above I have make the simplification mentioned above and drawn on the line of symetry.

Exploiting the symetry we can quickly see a large number of pairs of resistors that will have the same currents flowing through them and hence the same voltage across them.

If we want to actually find the currents the easiest way is to exploit the fact that as long as we maintain the symetry everything on the line of symetry will be at the same voltage, so we can remove the link between the left hand resistor pair and the central resistor pair without changing the voltages.

[image]

At this point the remaining solution is pretty trivial.

$$I_1 = I_2+I_3 = 1\mathrm{mA}$$

$$8I_2 = \frac{32}{3}I_3$$

$$I_3 = I_4+I_5$$

$$8I_4 = 2I_5$$

Comment: Could you tell me what points do have the same voltage across? I haven't seen any symmetry so far.

Comment: @morata Try redrawing the circuit in more familiar right angles remembering you can add or extend lines arbitrarily to connect nodes.